# Understanding Common Lisp do macro syntax

Tags: lisp, iteration, common-lisp

```lisp
(do ((n 0 (1+ n))
     (cur 0 next)
     (next 1 (+ cur next)))
    ((= 10 n) cur)))
```

This is an example from a Lisp textbook about the keyword `do`.

The `do` basic template is:

```
(do (variable-definitions*)
    (end-test-form result-form*)
 statement*)
```

But, for this example, it's not clear to me which part is which. And also, what do the middle 2 lines do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your good indentation clearly shows which part is which:

```
(do ((n 0 (1+ n))
    ^(cur 0 next)
    |(next 1 (+ cur next)))
    |
    +-- first argument of do

    ((= 10 n) cur)))
    ^
    |
    +-- start of second argument of do
```

Look, they line up nicely, and the inner material is indented:

```
   ((n 0 (1+ n))
    (cur 0 next)
    (next 1 (+ cur next)))
    ^
    |
    +- inner material of argument: three forms which are
       indented by 1 character and aligned together.
```

Your `do` doesn't have a third argument there: there is no body of statements (empty loop).

Answer (score 30):

```
(do ((n 0 (1+ n))  ;declares n, initially 0, n+1 each subsequent iteration)
     (cur 0 next)   ;declares cur, initially 0, then old value of next
     (next 1 (+ cur next))) ;declares next, initially 1, then the sum of (the old) cur and next
    ((= 10 n) ;end condition (ends when n = 10)
     cur)    ; return value
  ;empty body
  )
```

translating into c-like code

```
for(n=0, cur=0, next=1 ;
    !(n == 10) ;
    n=old_n+1, cur=old_next, next = old_cur + old_next)
{
    //do nothing 
    old_n = n;
    old_cur = cur;
    old_next = next;
}
return cur;
```

incidentally you should be able to see that this code returns the 10th Fibonacci number

---

**Optional EBNF/formal syntax:**

The syntax according to the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm) is:

```
(do ({var | (var [init-form [step-form]])}*) 
    (end-test-form result-form*) 
    declaration* 
    {tag | statement}*)
```

Understanding this requires knowledge of [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) and  big chunks of the Hyperspec

Comment: great idea to show C translation, using `old_` vars to simulate parallel assignment! Just to neat-pick: your Lisp code is mis-aligned  and has one extra closing parenthesis; your C code is missing the ending semicolon. :)

Comment: Looking at this translation, is it right to say the do macro is more like imperative programming, instead of functional programming?

Comment: @hyh yes and no --- common lisp is multi-paradigm, and this is an iterative construct that updates variables, which is certainly imperative. However this form returns a value, so you could use this loop as a return value, or as a condition in in if statement (i.e. `(if (> (this-fib-loop) 10) 'gt-10 'lte-10)` ) which is more functional

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it can help to 1. annotate the forms with comments and 2. print the current values in the body like so:

```
(do
 ;; varlist
 ((n 0 (1+ n))
  (cur 0 next)
  (next 1 (+ cur next)))
 ;; endlist
 ((= 10 n) cur)
  ;; body
  (print (list n cur next)))
```

This prints

```
(0 0 1) 
(1 1 1) 
(2 1 2) 
(3 2 3) 
(4 3 5) 
(5 5 8) 
(6 8 13) 
(7 13 21) 
(8 21 34) 
(9 34 55) 
55
```

which should clear matters up. @_@

Answer (score 0):

```
(do ((n 0 (1+ n))
     (cur 0 next)
     (next 1 (+ cur next)))
    ((= 10 n) cur))
```

do has 3 part.

1. variable
2. terminate condition
3. body

In this particular example there is no body. All real work done by 1. and 2. First it setup 3 vars and give initial value and step form. E.g. `n` set to 0 and during each iteration it steps further: `(1+ n)` which will increment the `n`

The terminate condition is `((= n 10) cur)` : when `n` equal to 10. Then return the `cur` as the whole return value of this `do` expression.

Combine all these, in this `do` example it will sum from 1 to 10 which yields 55

Comment: it's `result-form-n` not `action-n` also your second code block is badly indented.

Comment: you missed many parentheses there. Also, this calculates the sequence `(cur,next) = (0,1) (1,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,5) (5,8) (8,13) ...` of Fibonacci numbers, not just partial sum.